# how to change snapping degree

Tags: snapping

I want to snap my object (cylinder) like this
[image]

But what i got
[image]

I use snap to face, snap with closest, and the align rotation & project individual element is on. I tried to move the main point (the yellow point) but still not work. I'm trying to use another object like cube and it works. Can someone tell me where did it go wrong please? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Snap* uses the object's Z axis to stick perpendicularly to the target face, so in your case you need to rotate the origin 90°, at least temporarily:

- Enable the *Affect Only Origins* option in the *Options* panel on the top right of your 3D view:

[image]

- Rotate the origin so that its Z axis points perpendicularly to its current orientation:

[image]

- Disable the option, move your object until it snaps to the face you want:

[image]

You could also simply stick the object and rotate it on its own X or Y axis with <kbd>R</kbd> and double <kbd>X</kbd> or double <kbd>Y</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you so much